# Swipe down 10 times (Pull to refresh) IOS KIF

Tags: ios, kif-framework

I want to Pull to refresh 10 times

below code working for single time

```
tester().pullToRefreshView(withAccessibilityLabel: Home_Screen.PullToRefresh, pullDownDuration: KIFPullToRefreshTiming.inAboutOneSecond)
```